# Retrieving random data from sql database no repeat

Tags: c#, sql

Hi im creating a program where when the form loads random data will retrieve from the database and my problem is the code for not repeating the data again.
im using vb 2008 and sql database,
programming language : C#

for example:

```
Data in Database

Word_ID | Word
1 | eye
2 | cheese
3 | mouse
```

Then form loads it will retrieve random data and display in the label

example output:

cheese

so cheese now will not display on the next random

my code:

```
SqlConnection conn =
new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sony\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Hangman_Final\Hangman_Final\hangman_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Words from word order by NEWID()";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// display the results
while (reader.Read())
{
    string output = reader["Words"].ToString();
    label5.Text = output;
}

// close the connection
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How many words are in the database? Depending on entries, it would be more reliable to cache the words and pop them off as you need them, insuring you never get a duplicate. otherwise, you're going to need to test `WHERE word_id NOT IN (already found IDs)`

Comment: Adrian and Daryl Teo -the question is how can i prevent the repetition of the data
Brad -i have 40 words in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store words into `List<String>`. Get an element at random index from the list , print it and remove it.

Comment: I always have the same solution you have, Mr.AVD and you are always quicker.^_^

Comment: The efficiency of this approach will depend on the amount of words in DB and how often this list will be reloaded from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a matter of including the word that was just loaded as a 'and WORD <> 'PreviousWord'' in the where clause of you select statement?

Comment: You would need to track all previous words with this method not just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are storing the words along with an integer index in the database table, why not generate a random number (between the max number/index of words you have) in C# (using Random) and then fetch the word matching the index.

Answer (score 0):

Store the words in an collection and count it. Then use Random ? But this depends on how many words you got in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done this. As in your example, each record in the database has a numeric ID. I get the min and max ID and build a list of random numbers for whatever number of records I want. I exclude duplicate numbers during this process. Handling this in memory with an integer list is much faster than repeated database queries. Once the list of unique random numbers is created, then the records are pulled from the database using the members of the list as the criteria.

You can add in additional checks in case your ID's aren't sequential and for other conditions.